# Replacement for broken zipper in pants

Tags: clothing

I need to repair a pair of pants.  The zipper teeth are bent.  Looking at the stitching, replacing the zipper will take at least an hour or two.

What can be done to fix this in under 15 minutes?  I would like a permanent solution (not just a safety pin for a temporary fix).

I'm thinking perhaps using Velcro, but attaching it to the pants looks time consuming.  That said, Velcro could be a possible answer if it includes a method to affix it fairly quickly.

Comment: It will be grateful if you could share a zipper with teeth bent as an additional information.

Comment: @MANEESHMOHAN Hi Maneesh.  Are you referring to sharing a photograph, or perhaps something else?

Comment: Yes, please share a photograph of zipper with bent teeth

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use the Velcro.  There are many options out there; by either sewing it on, stick-on, or using heat.  If you are looking to save time, my suggestion would be the heat fusion technique.  This can come in either stick-on or heat activated.

If you are affixing this to denim, I would suggest heat activated fusion because the material is so thick.

[Stick-on Velcro](http://www.velcro.com/products/for-fabrics/900201__sticky-back-for-fabrics#/?shape=86d986b2d05347c08fc15520eba586f4&size=24in%20x%203/4in&color=0f7710dcd39341a08184085926cd57db)

[Iron-on Velcro](https://www.velcro.com/products/for-fabrics/900200__iron-on#/?shape=86d986b2d05347c08fc15520eba586f4&size=24in%20x%203/4in&color=2f0946dde4d8407b96fdb976c147323a)

[Sew-on Velcro](http://www.velcro.com/products/for-fabrics/900202__sew-on#/?shape=86d986b2d05347c08fc15520eba586f4&size=12in%20x%205/8in&color=2f0946dde4d8407b96fdb976c147323a)

Answer (score 0):

Safety pin and long shirt to cover the fly.

Then, ASAP, change pants.